# YII retrieving session from db

Tags: database, session, yii, session-state

I'm using mysql database to store the user session data.
I redirect the user to another server with the session id as a variable (GET), and then i need to retrieve the session from the DB using the ID.

code used in my remote server:

```
  Yii::app()->session->sessionID = $sessionID;
  Yii::app()->session->open();
```

the result is that the session gets overridden with no data (new session is opened).
how do i retrieve the session from DB? do i need to create a model for the table or can i use YII session functionality?

thanks,
Danny

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create a model for session table due to [CDbHttpSession](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession) `relies on PDO to access database`.

What is the configuration of your session component?

You specify session ID and start the session manually by calling [open()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#open-detail) method. This method [sets session callback methods](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/blob/1.1.13/framework/web/CHttpSession.php#L116) using PHP's [session_set_save_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php) function. [readSession($id)](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#readSession-detail) is among them and according to `session_set_save_handler`'s manual page:

> This callback is called internally by PHP when the session starts or when session_start() is called.

Due to [session_start](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) `creates a session or resumes the current one` you have to grant that session is not started automatically before setting session's identifier. [autoStart](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#autoStart-detail) property of Yii's session instance is responsible for that and must be set to `false` (defaults to `true`).

Also an indentifier [connectionID](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession#connectionID-detail) of your database connection to retrieve session data through must be specified. It's important, otherwise:

> If not set, a SQLite database will be automatically created and used.

Keeping it all in mind I suppose that configuration of your session component must look like:

```
'session' => array(
    'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
    'autoStart' => false,
    'connectionID' => 'db',
    'sessionTableName' => 'your_session_table_name',
    'autoCreateSessionTable' => false    // for performance reasons
)
```

Comment: this is exactly how my configuration looks :) ... now you say all i need is to retrieve the session using standard YII query builder?

Comment: BTW you dont have to use sessionTableName if you want to use the default - YIISession

Comment: thanks, worked like a charm! didnt need to use the query builder after adding autostart = false.

Answer (score 0):

php stores sessionid in cookie with this name ( PHPSESSID )   yii also store session id in browser's cookie( because it uses php default sessions). 
If you change PHPSESSID varaible in cookie , you will be able to change our session. 
Simply you must do that

`setcookie('PHPSESSID',$sessionId);`// where $sessionId is your session id you read from db and this session must exists.

Comment: that is not how the session is set i'm afraid...i keep the session id with all variables and data (as an object) in the DB itself. see: CDbHttpSession - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbHttpSession